# Search through the local.Storage items and rename the item if any item with a given name rule is found

Tags: javascript, html

I have many local.Storage items with the following name types:
o-e1_XXXX_XX,
o-e1_YYYY_YY
.
.
.
and so on..

however, there is no certainty that these items exist in the storage. i want to find a way to search through all the local.Storage items whose names start with "o-eN_" where N is any integer >= 1. If this item is found then it should be renamed to "o-e(N-1)_" i.e. - name it with an integer one less than the integer in its name and the original item should be deleted.

Comment: That sounds like a great task. Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: yup! what i have been thinking of is.. to store the names of all the items created (existing) in a separate item and then access it as a reference for the names of the existing items and then use for loop to do the renaming, storing the contents of the item temporarily in a variable while the renaming is done..
but then the whole purpose is defeated because i never "searched" for the items. and i think this is a slow and tedious way.. but i can't think of anything else..

Comment: I think lan meant that we need to see some code. It is difficult to understand what are the exact problems you are having. It sounds like you should use regular expressions (or [verbal expressions](https://github.com/VerbalExpressions/JSVerbalExpressions)) for searching and replacing but maybe you know that already.